# Using different databases for development vs production Flask

Tags: flask, development-environment, production

I have a flask app that uses a different database based on production vs development environment variables. I am worried about a developer forgetting to set FLASK_ENV=development before running their local flask app, and suddenly they are making updates to a production database.

My only easy solution I have thought of is restricting the production DB to only accept requests from the production server IP so that way everything will error out if the developer forgets to set the environment variable, but I was wondering if there are better solutions for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is a good practice to limit access to your production database to trusted IPs only.

---

As you can read in [Configuration Handling: Development/Production (Flask Docs)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#development-production), you can have multiple configurations and use inheritance.

```
class Config(object):
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:'

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@localhost/foo'

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    pass
```

You can load, all the time, the default configuration that is safe. Only if the production environment variable is set, the real database configuration will be loaded.

Another solution is to use the [instance folder (Flask Docs)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#instance-folders) that **mustn't be** a part of your git repository.

> The instance folder is designed to not be under version control and be deployment-specific.

So, when you deploy your app, just add your production configuration to this instance folder, and nobody would have the prod configuration on their local machine. 
*They have a few examples and explain very well how to use it in the link that I gave you above.*

Answer (score 0):

You can prewrite the environment variables in `.flaskenv`:

```
FLASK_ENV=development
```

Then install `python-dotenv`:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Now if you run your application locally with `flask run`, Flask will automatically read the `.flaskenv` and set the environment variables in it.