# Connecting to a local MongoDB and MongoDB Atlas

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a local app, that uses MongoDB Community Server, and I intend to deploy it to GCloud. I have also created a MongoDB Atlas DB, collection and document.

How do I configure my local version to use Community Server and the production version to use Atlas?

I've searched around, but I guess I don't know what to look for.

Secondly, is that the right method to go down?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is that somehow in the context of some application development framework, like e.g. Django? That may have support for different environments, which you could use. As it stands, the answer is "use `if`", which probably isn't of much help.

Comment: Can you mention the framework you are using. Generel way to do it in below answer.

Comment: I don't see springboot mentioned anywhere, @YJR. I replied because the question is unclear, in other words.

Comment: Yes, exactly.
It's for a Flask app that I've built.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python configParser for this task. Create a config.ini file as fillow.

```
[dev]
mongo_url = ...        
          
[prod]
mongo_url = ...
```

In the file where you want to get the mongo url add following lines.

```
import configparser
import sys
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
version = sys.argv[0]
mongo_url = config[version].mongo_url
```

Then you can pass version (dev/prod) as a argument as follows.

```
py app.py dev
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The suggestions opened a few doors and led me to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222386/using-different-databases-for-development-vs-production-flask . Which I'll explore as well.